# As simple as 1,2,3?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

What is the next number in the sequence?

> 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 5, 6, 10, 16, 7, 11, 8, 25, 12, 17, 13, 14, 18, 36, 15, 26, 19, 20, 21, 49, 27, 22, 23, 28, 37, 24, 29, 64, 30, 31, 38, 32, 33, 50, 39, 81, 34, 40, 35, 41, 42, 51, 43, 44, 45, 100, 65, ?

**Clue 1**: Insert the next number into the sequence!

**Clue 2**: Insert first, check later!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 52

If we build the sequence **one number at a time**, we can use the following rules:
(I used 1-based indexing for this which may explain why there are some adjustments by one.

> **Rule 1: If the number is a perfect square, for number 'n', insert it at position '(n/2)+1', rounded down.**
>  1 is the first perfect square. For 1, (1/2)+1, rounded down = 1 so we insert 1 at position 1.

> **Rule 2: After inserting a perfect square at position 'p', successive numbers p1, p2, etc. should be inserted at position p1 = p+p/2, p2 = p1+p/4, p3 = p2+p/8, etc., rounded up, until we reach  the next perfect square.**
>  *Note that if you tried to insert a number at position greater than the current length of the sequence, p here is the position it was actually inserted at.*

> 2 is 1+1/2, rounded up = 2, so we insert 2 at position 2.
>  3 is 2+1/4, rounded up = 3, so we insert 3 at position 3.
>  This gets us 1, 2, 3

> 4 is a perfect square. For 4, (4/2)+1 = 3, so we get: 1, 2, 4, 3

> For 5, we inserted 4 at position 3. 3 + 3/2 rounded up is 5.
>  At this point we carry on the sequence and get:
>  1 2 4 3 9 5 6 10 16 7 11 8 25 12 17 13 14 18 36 15 26 19 20 21 49 27 22 23 28 37 24 29 64 30 31 38 32 33 50 39 81 34 40 35 41 42 51 43 44 45 100 65

Continuing the sequence, we get (roughly, I stopped adding to the end after 67; 81 and 100 fall within this range, but any other numbers after 67 are beyond this range, so these first few should be correct, barring counting errors (It was a lot of counting)):

> 52 47 48 53 66 67...
>  So the missing number is *52*

Extra:
This was difficult to explain well, so here is some raw data that may make the pattern clearer:

```
* may have some errors; it was a lot of counting *

#   position increment
1   1   
2   2   
3   3   
4   3   after 2
5   5   
6   6   
7   7   
8   8   
9   5   after 4.5
10  8   +3
11  10  +2
12  12  +1
13  13  
14  14  
15  15  
16  9   after 8
17  14  +5
18  17  +3
19  19  +2
20  20  +1
21  21  
22  22  
23  23  
24  24  
25  13  after 12.5
26  20  +7
27  24  +4
28  27  +3
29  29  +2
30  30  
31  31  
32  32  
33  33  
34  34  
35  35  
36  19  after 18
37  29  +10
38  34  +5
39  37  +3
40  39  +2
41  41  +2
42  42  
43  43  
44  44  
45  45  
46  46  
47  47  
48  48  
49  25  after 24
50  38  +13
51  45  +7
52  49  +4
53  52  +3
54  54  +2
55  55  +1
56  56  
57  57  
58  58  
59  59  
60  60  
61  61  
62  62  
63  63  
64  33  after 32
65  50  +17
66  59  +9
67  64  +5
…       
81  41  after 40.5
82  62  +21>+15
…       
100 51  after 50
101 77  +26
```

Comment: Perfect! I was really hoping someone would be able to solve it! At first I only gave Clue 1, but [the SE system rejected](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4981) so I added Clue 2. Hope you enjoyed it!

Comment: By the way, here is a short piece of Javascript to verify the answer: "`function cut() { n=u.length; m=(n+n%2)/2; t=t.concat(u.slice(0,m)); u=u.slice(m,n); }
t=[]; c=0; for(a=1;a<=10;a++) { u=t.slice(); t=[]; for(s=a*a;s<(a+1)*(a+1);s++) { cut(); t.push(s); } console.log(t+""); }`". It can be run in any browser console. We do not need to run further because 11^2 = 121 would be inserted after the first 120/2 = 60 terms, and later numbers even further.